# Problem with imageLoadFunction, DOMException: The source image cannot be decoded

Tags: openlayers, wms, openlayers-8

I tried openlayers 8 and ran into a problem. When using the imageloadfunction, I get the following exception:
DOMException: The source image cannot be decoded.
The same code works for me in all previous versions of openlayers, so I downgraded to version 7.5.2

```
    this.imageLayer = new ImageLayer({
      source: new ImageWMS({
        url: lay.geoUrlWms,
        //url: environment.serverUrl + '/wms/getMap?url=' + encoded + '&uuid=' + lay.uuid,
        imageLoadFunction: function (tile: Image, src) {

          var client = new XMLHttpRequest();

          client.responseType = 'blob';
          const encoded = encodeURIComponent(src);

          client.open('GET', environment.serverUrl + '/wms/getMap?url=' + encoded + '&uuid=' +            lay.uuid);

            headers.forEach((value, key) => {
            client.setRequestHeader(key, value);
          });

          client.onload = function () {
            const image = tile.getImage() as HTMLImageElement;
            image.src = URL.createObjectURL(client.response);
          };
          client.send();
        },
        params: {
          'LAYERS': lay.layerName,
          'TILED': true,
          // 'CQL_FILTER': cqlAll
        },
        serverType: 'geoserver'
      }),
      visible: true,
    });
```

I try everything :). Expected to solve my problem.

Comment: Update to the dev version or wait for the next release, see https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/15093 and https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/15109